# How to display other layouts?

Tags: java, android

I am new at android development and just trying to learn along the way!

I am creating an android app that I would like to show different views, one for weight, weather, and hydration (are what I have called them for now). Although when I run my app I only get my one view displayed.

What code do I have to add/modify in order to display the other two layouts in the tabbed view?

Here is my code in MainActivity.java

```
    package com.oxinc.android.drate;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int quantity = 0;
    String outcome = "";
    int required = 0;
    int height = 0;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        //Tabbed Layout
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        //Floating Action Button
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Are you hydrated?", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public static PlaceholderFragment fragment_main() {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment weight(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View hydration = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hydration, container, false);
            return hydration;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.weight(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Hydration";
                case 1:
                    return "Weigh In";
                case 2:
                    return "Weather";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

        public void eight(View view) {
            quantity = quantity + 8;
            displayQuantity(quantity);
        }

        public void twelve(View view) {
            quantity = quantity + 12;
            displayQuantity(quantity);
        }

        public void sixteen(View view) {
            quantity = quantity + 16;
            displayQuantity(quantity);
        }

        public void thirty_two(View view) {
            quantity = quantity + 32;
            displayQuantity(quantity);
        }

        public void sixty_four(View view) {
            quantity = quantity + 64;
            displayQuantity(quantity);
        }

        //Reset Button
        public void reset(View view) {
            quantity = 0;
            displayQuantity(quantity);
            outcome = "";
            displayOutcome(outcome);
        }

        //Starts the basic formula for oz. per day
        public int height(int value) {
            EditText height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
            String height_value = height.getText().toString();
            int int_height = Integer.parseInt(height_value);

            if (int_height >= 60) {
                required = 64;
            }
            return required;
        }
        /**
         * This method is called when the check button is clicked.
         */
        public String check(View view) {

            height((int) height);
            if (quantity >= required) {
                outcome = "You have met your goal!!";
            } else {
                outcome = "Keep trying you are almost there";
            }
            displayOutcome(outcome);
            return outcome;
        }

        //Displays the Outcome to the outcome text view
        public void displayOutcome(String n) {
            TextView outcomeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(
                    R.id.outcome_text_view);
            outcomeTextView.setText(outcome);
        }

        /**
         * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
         */
        public void displayQuantity(int quantity) {
            TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(
                    R.id.quantity_text_view);
            quantityTextView.setText(quantity + "");
        }

}
```

An once I run it I just get three screens that look like this...

[image]

Comment: You mean the three tabs show same content?

Comment: @statosdotcom yes all three of the tabs show the exact same view, how would I make three separate views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your 
`public Fragment getItem(int position) {`
which is inside your
`public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {` 
Implement this:

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new fragment1();
            case 1:
                return new fragment2();
            case 2:
                return new fragment3();
            default:
                // this should never happen
                return null;
                //return new Fragment();
        }
    }
```

Where "fragment1-2 and 3" are the name of the java classes you've defined to run there.

I use my "getItem" exactly this way, with nothing more inside it. So I don't know if you have to maintain your `return PlaceholderFragment.weight(position + 1);` there. Try commenting it out and see what happens. I don't use createview either. Best.

Comment: Thank you this worked, I deleted the  return    PlaceholderFragment.weight(position + 1); that was there as starter code generated by Android Studio

Comment: Thank you Fidel_Willis. Check about createview too, as stated by Sampaio. This really can cause unpredictable behavior. Keep it up man.

Comment: I wish I could up vote your answer, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: My pleasure! Don't be afraid, you've already got much knowledge, as seen by the level of your post and speedy handling of the situation. To higher your reputation it's just a matter of time. You don't owe me nothing at all, I already got what I wanted: help people, get some points. You have a long way to go. Be thought. You'll help lots o people in the future, I trust you. God bless.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View hydration = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hydration, container, false);
        return hydration;
    }
```

You are always inflating the hydration layout, in every fragment

Comment: Could the app still work without using this entire class? Could I delete the whole thing?